# Override constructor in all subclasses IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I wanted to know if there is possibility to generate `constructors` for all subclasses in `IntelliJ`.
I mean if i have many subclasses and somewhere in development stage I wanted to add new `constructor`, with a flag, for example. Is there a way to generate this `constructor` in all subclasses too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I wanted to know if there is possibility to generate constructors for all
subclasses in IntelliJ?
```

The answer would be no and one of the reason would because it is design specific.

When you create a subclass and define a non default constructor in it you have the liberty to call any one of the overloaded superclass constructor from it. Which one would be design choice as initialization of superclass variables may depend on it. Never the less call to one of the overloaded super class constructor must be 1st statement of  subclass constructor. If you do not provide any, call to default constructor of super class is inserted by default by the JVM. However in that case if your super class does not have default constructor(you have explicitly provided some parameterized constructor) then compiler error will occur.

Comment: Thanks, I know JAVA. I have constructor Constr(a, b, c) and override in it multiple subclasses. Then I want to create Constr(a, b, c, d) and add it to all subclasses too. Isn't it possible to automatically generate it for all subclasses? i can do it for one class, why can't I do it for all of them at a time?

Comment: Because when you define Constr(a, b, c, d) in super class you may want to create the same constructor in subclass and call super(a,b,c,d) in it. But I may need Constr(a, b, c) in subclass and call super(a,b,c,defaultValue). What you want is your specific requirement and IDE wont provide support for it.

Comment: Well, I hoped they would prepare template for me. Okay, so the answer is no. Thanks!